# Facing Package Update Issue When Upgrade Laravel Version 8 To 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Problem 1

> Root composer.json requires grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial dev-l9-compatibility, found grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial[dev-test-issue-26, dev-fix/locale-polyfill, dev-master, dev-srid, dev-mysql-5.6, dev-mysql 2.0.0, ..., 2.2.3, 3.0.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master), 5.0.0]

but it does not match the constraint.

facing this error when i upgrade my laravel version 8 to 9.

i have include this package also in my composer.json

`"grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial": "*",`

Comment: what is your MySQL version ?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with your MySQL version, not in PHP.

If you're just upgrading PHP and not MySQL, then you have to use

```
composer require grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial:^1.0
```

---

[image]

Comment: what is your MySQL version ?